# There exist $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$ such $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=c？$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ramsey-theory

Let $ A$ and $ B$ are two infinite subsets of the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$,  such that
$$A\cap B=\emptyset \qquad A\cup B=\mathbb N$$

**Question:** is it true that for every natural $c>0$, 
 there exist two increasing sequences $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$ such that 
$\{a_{n}\}\subseteq  A,\{b_{n}\}\subseteq  B$ and 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{a_{n}}{b_{n}}=c?$$

My try: maybe I guess  there doesn't exist such this condition $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$

Thank you for you help

Comment: The phrase “for any natural $c>0$” is oddly placed in the question. Is this about the existence of such sequences for every natural number $c$?

Comment: Thank you,@HaraldHanche-Olsen,I have edit it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE 12/02/2013** The first version of this answer was incorrect
(it used a false version of Ramsey’s theorem, for ordered tuples instead
of unordered tuples). The corrected version below does not use Ramsey’s
theorem.

---

The answer to your question is YES.
The case $c=1$ is simpler than the others and has been explained in 
Harald's comment below.
Also, the problem stays the same if we replace $A$ by $B$, $B$ by
$A$, and $c$ by $\frac{1}{c}$.
So we may assume without loss of generality that $c > 1$.

It will suffice to show the following : for any $\varepsilon >0$ and any
integer $m$, there are integers $a\in A,b\in B$ with $a\geq m,b\geq m$, such that

$$
c-\varepsilon \leq \frac{a}{b} \leq c+\varepsilon \tag{1}
$$

So suppose that this is false for some $\varepsilon >0$ and some
$m$. We then have, for any $(a,b)\in A\times B$ such that $a,b\geq m$,

$$
\frac{a}{b} < c-\varepsilon \text{ or }
c+\varepsilon < \frac{a}{b} \tag{2}
$$

We may assume that $c-\varepsilon > 1$ (this will be true for small
enough $\varepsilon$).

Let $M_1=\frac{c^2-\varepsilon^2+c}{\varepsilon(c-\varepsilon)}$,
$M_2=\frac{2}{\varepsilon}$, $M_3=\frac{c+\varepsilon+2}{c+\varepsilon-1}$,
$M_4=\frac{c+c^2-\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon(c-\varepsilon)}$
and $M={\sf max}(m,M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4)$.

**Lemma 1** If $B$ contains an integer interval 
$I=\big[\big|x,y\big|\big]=\lbrace x,x+1,x+2,\ldots ,y \rbrace$ with
$x\geq M$. Then $B$ also contains the interval
$J=\big[\big| \ 1+\lceil(c-\varepsilon)x\rceil,
\lfloor(c+\varepsilon)(y-1)\rfloor \ \ \big|\big]$.

**Proof of lemma 1**  Let $w\in J$. Consider the numbers

$$
\alpha=\frac{w}{c+\varepsilon}+1, \beta=\frac{w}{c-\varepsilon}-1
$$

We have

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
\beta-\alpha &=& \frac{2}{c^2-\varepsilon^2}(w-\frac{c^2-\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon})
\geq \frac{2}{c^2-\varepsilon^2} ((c-\varepsilon)x+1-\frac{c^2-\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon}) \geq 0 \ (\text{because } x\geq M_1) \\
y-\alpha &=& \frac{(c+\varepsilon)(y-1)-w}{c+\varepsilon} \geq 0 \\
\beta-x &=& \frac{w-(c-\varepsilon)x-1}{c-\varepsilon} \geq 0
\end{array}
$$

We deduce ${\sf max}(x,\alpha) \leq {\sf min}(y,\beta)$ and hence
${\sf max}(x,\lceil\frac{w}{c+\varepsilon}\rceil) 
\leq {\sf min}(y,\lfloor\frac{w}{c+\varepsilon}\rfloor)$. Let $b$ be any integer
between those two integers. Then $b\in[|x,y|]$ so $b\in B$, but at the same time
$b\in [|\frac{w}{c+\varepsilon},\frac{w}{c-\varepsilon}|]$, so 
$c-\varepsilon \leq \frac{w}{b} \leq c+\varepsilon$. By (2) we see that $w$ cannot be
in $A$, so it must be in $B$.

**Lemma 2** If $B$ contains an integer interval 
$I=\big[\big|x,y\big|\big]=\lbrace x,x+1,x+2,\ldots ,y \rbrace$ with
$x\geq M$ and $y\geq (c-\frac{\varepsilon}{2})x$, then $y+1\in B$.

**Proof of lemma 2** We have $y+1\geq (c-\frac{\varepsilon}{2})x+1 \geq (c-\varepsilon)x+2$
(because $x\geq M_2$). So $y+1\geq 1+\lceil(c-\varepsilon)x\rceil$. 
Also, we have $y+1 \leq (c+\varepsilon)(y-1)-1$ (because $y \geq x \geq M_3$).
In the end we have $y+1\in J$, so lemma 1 applies.

**Lemma 3** $B$ cannot contain an   integer interval 
$I=\big[\big|x,y\big|\big]=\lbrace x,x+1,x+2,\ldots ,y \rbrace$ with
$x\geq M$ and $y\geq (c-\frac{\varepsilon}{2})x$.

**Proof of lemma 3** If it did, we could iterate lemma 2 to deduce
that B contains every integer $\geq x$, contradicting the infinitude of 
$A$.

**Lemma 4** The interval $J=[|x_J,y_J|]$ defined in lemma 1 satisfies
$x_J \geq x$ and 
$\frac{y_J}{x_J} \geq (1+\frac{\varepsilon}{c-\varepsilon})\frac{y}{x}$.

**Proof of lemma 4** We have $(c+\varepsilon)(x-1)-1 \geq x$ because of
$x\geq M_3$, so $x_J \geq x$.

Next, we have $1 \geq 
\frac{c^2-\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon(c-\varepsilon)x-c}$ because of
$x\geq M_1$. We deduce $y\geq x \geq \frac{c^2-\varepsilon^2}{\varepsilon(c-\varepsilon)x-c}$,
so $(\varepsilon(c-\varepsilon)x-c)y \geq (c^2-\varepsilon^2)x$, which is equivalent
to $\frac{(c+\varepsilon)(y-1)}{1+(c-\varepsilon)x} \geq (1+\frac{\varepsilon}{c-\varepsilon})\frac{y}{x}$, which
implies  $\frac{y_J}{x_J} \geq (1+\frac{\varepsilon}{c-\varepsilon})\frac{y}{x}$.

**Conclusion of proof** Since $B$ is infinite, there is a $x_0\in B$
such that $x_0 \geq M$. Let $y_0=x_0$. Iterating lemmata 1 and 4,
we find for each $n$ an integer interval $I=[|x_n,y_n|]$ with
$x_n \geq M$ and $\frac{y_n}{x_n} \geq 
\bigg(1+\frac{\varepsilon}{c-\varepsilon}\bigg)^n$.

We then have $\frac{y_n}{x_n} > c-\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ for large enough
$n$, contradicting
lemma 3.

Comment: Wow. You had to invoke Ramsey's theorem for that? Well, on second thought it seems reasonable. The case $c=1$ is so deceptively simple (there are infinitely many neighbour pairs with one in each set), one could be forgiven for not realizing how much harder the other cases are.

Comment: @Ewan Delanoy, In the first case,for $q\in M$ why $\beta_{q}$ is an integer larger than any $(c-\varepsilon)\alpha_{p}$,not $\alpha_{p}\le \beta_{q}(c-\varepsilon)$?

Comment: sorry,I don't understand your solution,why By Ramsey;s theorem ,then is an infinite subset $M\subset \{m,m+1,\cdots,\},\dfrac{\alpha_{p}}{\beta_{q}}\le c-\varepsilon?$,can you explain? Thank you

Comment: @nanchangjian corrected, thanks.

Comment: @chinamath $f(p,q)=1$ means that $\frac{\alpha_p}{\beta_q} \leq c-\varepsilon$

Comment: I mean why use  Ramseys theorem ?

Comment: Ramseys:Let X be some countably infinite set and colour the elements of X(n) (the subsets of X of size n) in c different colours. Then there exists some infinite subset M of X such that the size n subsets of M all have the same colour.  I can't understand this problem reasonable?

Comment: @chinamath please see my update